# Python Get Property if Object is not None

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a Pythonic way to grab a property if an object exists on one line of code? Currently in the code below if someone passes in a None type object the code will break, so I need some clean way to check that it is not None, but on one line of code. C# has the `?.` syntax that works really well, so looking for something like that.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__():
        self.my_property = "Hello, World!"

def print_class_property(myClassInstance):
    print(myClassInstance???.my_property) # Here is where I need something inline
```

Comment: Why one line? Just because something terse doesn't make it better. Anyway, you can use `getattr`.

Comment: If someone passes None to your `print_class_property`, that's their bug, not yours. That said, Python doesn't have a null-coalescing operator or anything like that.

Comment: Because these objects are properties on a list of objects and I have to do this check about 20 times. I can do a null check everytime but it feels like Python should have something.

Comment: getattr won't work because it assumes the object already exists

Comment: @CamJohnson26 See my answer.

Comment: @CamJohnson26 `getattr` has a `default` argument. Usually in Python, you would probably just use `try: ... except AttributeError` That would be considered [*Pythonic*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python)

Comment: why not `b = a.attr if a is not None else 'some default value'`?

Comment: or if you don't mind all false values then you can use `b = a and a.attr or None`

Comment: @khachik i think the reason is a.attr may not have yet existed causing a keyerror

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). It allows an optional third argument that will be returned if the object passed in doesn't have the specified attribute. From the docs:

> ### getattr(object, name[, default])
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`. **If the named attribute does not exist, *default* is returned if provided**, otherwise AttributeError is raised.

Bold emphasis mine.

```
>>> getattr(None, 'attr', 'default')
'default'
```

Here's an example pertaining more to your problem:

```
>>> class Class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = 'attr'

        
>>> def func(obj):
    return getattr(obj, 'attr', 'default')

>>> func(Class())
'attr'
>>> func(None)
'default'
```

As @juanpa.arrivillaga said in the comments, another common idiom when dealing with cases such as this is to use [`try/except`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=try#try). See [*What is the EAFP principle in Python?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python).

Comment: This worked great for me, thanks. Any idea why the 3rd parameter isn't documented?

Comment: @ChristianDean: Those are square brackets. Angle brackets are `<>`.

Comment: @user2357112 That's what I meant. Thanks for the correct.

Comment: I didn't know that default value will be used if the object is None. I thought it was only when the parameter was None or non-existing. That's a life saver !